# Using LLVM as a compiler backend on Windows - external tools required?

Tags: windows, llvm

I've been browsing the LLVM documentation, and I've got to ask about the availability of back-ends for Windows. Their [examples](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) for getting up and running on Windows still use the Visual Studio linker to create the resulting executable files. The [JIT example](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html) is much cleaner, but I need to create output PE files, not JIT the code in-process.

What I'd like to ask is if there exists an LLVM backend which can perform virtually all of the necessary functions to go from LLVM IR to executable PE file, including handling the importing of Win32 functions from the kernel, and preferably, handling COM types as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly not. LLVM itself doesn't handle any of the linking stages, it's just a compiler, so you'll need to integrate it with the Windows SDK linker, or the linker from MinGW.

Comment: You lie! `llvm-as` and `llvm-ld`, when used in combination, will produce an executable file.

Comment: @DeadMG, no, you're wrong. llvm-ld will just produce as "thing wrapper". The binary will just execute the LLVM IR via JIT, it's not a standalone file.

Comment: yeah- apparently, I had an old install of Cygwin, and it was using GCC to produce the executable file.